# How to run code at a specific time in swift

Tags: swift

I've looked all over but I can't find an answer to this question. I want a specific function to run at 6:00 am and 6:00 pm every day for a day/night mode in my app. This doesn't need to run in the background, just when the app is open, but I also want to prefom other functions of the app as well while it checks for the time.

Comment: This might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time

Comment: Trigger this event when app finishes launches and specify that selector in your appdelegate. It will run on the basis of that whenver in foreground try by triggering a notification.

Comment: So, if there’s no background operation and the user fires up the app at 6:05, am I correct in assuming you want to do what it would have done at 6:00 as soon as the user fires up the app at 6:05?

Comment: And assuming that’s the case, what if they fire up the app at 11pm one day and then next started it again at 5:58pm the next day, at which point it does what it would have at 6:00am. But then do you want to do it again 2 minutes later? In short, is it really as simple as 6am and 6pm, or is it really “do it if more than 12 hours have transpired” or some combination thereof?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like this. Just set a `Date` with the `Calendar` object. Put your specific time in military hours (from 00:00 to 23:59, with 00:00 being midnight) and Voila!, if your app is in the foreground and the specified time kicks in, you will see the function you used as the selector execute

Give it a shot and happy coding

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current 

    let now = Date()
    let date = calendar.date(
        bySettingHour: 23,
        minute: 52,
        second: 0,
        of: now)!
    
    let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

func runCode() {
    print("Do whatever here")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you know if this interferes with the device's battery life?

Comment: to be honest I don't know the impact for the battery life

Comment: No problem, if someone else finds a more performant way to do it we can update this answer too

Comment: Does this code executes when app suspended ?

Comment: @user12766300 if you want to optimize for increased power savings and responsiveness, make use of the tolerance parameter when creating the Timer. Source - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415085-tolerance